# Derby/JavaDB char encoding - size on disk

Tags: database, encoding, size, derby, javadb

I want to calculate the size my JavaDB database will need and therefore I need to know how char is encoded to know how many bytes it will use on disk.

Does anyone know which character encoding Derby uses? I have read that Derby uses Unicode, but couldn't find any information about the encoding (neither in the reference manual, nor any other pages).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's UTF8.

However, whenever I'm trying to figure out how much disk space my database will use, I always use a benchmarking approach: write a little test program that generates a sample database, using sample test data, taking care to try to make that data as representative of your application as you can. Generate enough data to be realistic (e.g., at least 10,000 rows).

Generate some nice round number of rows, like 10,000 or 100,000, or 1,000,000. Then look at the actual database files that Derby created on disk, see how large they are, do a little bit of match, and you can figure out your result.

The nice thing about an approach like this is that it will help you catch mistakes like: forgetting an entire secondary index, or not understanding that your UNIQUE constraint added a bunch of overhead behind the scenes, or forgetting to count some of the columns that you thought wouldn't matter, but turned out to take a substantial amount of space.